# How to just show x-axis (at y = 0) using chartkick (chart.js)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chart.js, chartkick

I want to just have the x-axis at y = 0 showing on my bar chart, i.e. the just the green line shown below.

[image]

What chart.js/chartkick configuration should I use to achieve this? Or do I have to directly plot it? If so, how do I achieve this?

At the moment, I have the following chart.js configuration, which has removed all lines including the desired x-axis.

```
library: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                display: false,
            },
            gridLines: {
                display: false,
            }
        }],
        xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                display: false,
            },
            gridLines: {
                display: false
            }
        }],
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using Chart.js version 2.9.4, this could be done by defining `yAxis.gridLines` as follows:

```
gridLines: {
  lineWidth: 0,
  zeroLineWidth: 3,
  zeroLineColor: 'rgb(101, 157, 52)',
  z: 10
}
```

> For further details about individual [grid line options](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/2.9/docs/axes/styling.md#grid-line-configuration), please consult Chart.js v2.9 documentation.

Please take a look at below runnable code and see how it works.

```js
new Chart('chart', {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'My Dataset',
      data: [50, -15, 30],
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(0, 0, 255)',
      borderWidth: 2
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          display: false
        },
        gridLines: {
          lineWidth: 0,
          zeroLineWidth: 3,
          zeroLineColor: 'rgb(101, 157, 52)',
          z: 10
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          display: false
        },
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
canvas {
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" height="120"></canvas>
```